# How to set google map with bottomsheet in flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, bottom-sheet

I want to have functionality like this [click here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/5357526/11641271/097c35d0-9d40-11e5-94c6-f9bef5f5ab9d.gif) in flutter. I have to use bottomsheet along with google map, i had shown google map but feeling problem in showing bottomsheet above google map

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Stack` widget. It stacks widgets in top of each other.

Also you should haver your Bottom sheet inside a `Positioned` widget. Something like this.

```
return Stack(
    children: [
        GoogleMap(),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0
            right: 0.0
            left: 0.0
            child: BottomSheet(),
        ),
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a package you can use [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel)